# Casting between inherited classed

Tags: c#, casting

The following cast doent work. I think it should, can you explain to me why not? Both `WebserviceErrorMessage` and `BTMacResponse` inherit from the `WebserviceMessage` class

```
       DataLayer.WebserviceMessage msg = new Service.WebserviceErrorMessage(ex) ;
       DataLayer.BTMacResponse macrsp = (DataLayer.BTMacResponse)msg;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless `WebserviceErrorMessage` inherits from `BTMacResponse`, I don't see why this should work. You're trying to cast a value to `BTMacResponse` when the object simply *isn't* a `BTMacResponse`.

To put it another way, would you expect to be able to cast a `FileStream` to a `MemoryStream` just because they both inherit from `Stream`?

Would you expect to be able to cast a `Button` to a `String` just because they both inherit from `Object`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast that way. The following is illegal:

```
class Base {

}

class A : Base {

}

class B: Base {
}

Base someBase = new A();
B someB = (B)someBase;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast down the hierarchy because when you create an object of the parent, you do not create the child object with it, however when you create an object of the child an instance of the parent is created, thats why you can upcast and not downcast.

in your case you can cast DataLayer.WebserviceMessage to its children and not the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

there is no contractor for DataLayer.BTMacResponse that get DataLayer.WebserviceMessage as a parameter you need to implement this:

```
public BTMacResponse(WebserviceMessage w)
        {
                // copy stuff to 'this'
        }

        public static implicit operator BTMacResponse(WebserviceMessage w)
        {
                BTMacResponse b = new BTMacResponse(w);
                return b;
        }
```